# How to clear click counter from outside function with .on in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a function with .on() like this:

```
$('#gallery').on('click', '.gon', function() {   
    countn = ($(this).data("click_count") || 0) + 1;
    $(this).data("click_count", countn);
    // set up for first move
    if ( countn == 1 ) {
         do something........
```

countn is the variable that count the clicks.
Now I want to clear or reset "countn" from outside of this function like:

```
$('.teaserbox').click(function() {    
    countn = 0; 
    return false;       
});
```

This doesn't work.
Is there a way to clear/reset the variable insde the first function from outside?

Comment: There is no single variable for this. Each `.gon` element has its own click counter, stored in `data("click_count")`. Which one do you want to reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The count value is stored as data on the object clicked and resetting the variable `countn`in your reset function does nothing since countn is not defined in that scope before.

I don't know if you have more than one `.gon` element in `#gallery`, but if you do you can really only reset them all. This is done like this

```
$('.teaserbox').click(function() {
    $('#gallery .gon').data('click_count', 0);
});
```

You could of course use the `.teaserbox` (which will be `$(this)`in the function) in the event with `find()` to find the correct `.gon` element and reset only the count for that element.

On another note you are forgetting your `var` statements in your function, it's important because implicitly declaring variables causes all kind of problems down the road.

Comment: This doesn't work.I've now made a example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/actree/pNkMM/18/). Reset and alert after clicking fist div some times. Countn istn't reset. What's wrong?

Comment: You extra variable countn is causing this. You are not resseting the variable, but in general I think you should decide to use only `.data()` or the `var countn`, not a mix of both which is causing problems right now.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand. I've tested that here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/actree/pNkMM/25/) and remover the var countn. Same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

the variable countn should be accessable from both functions.
i put everything in an anonymous function, so only both click event handler can access the variable.

```
(function () {
 var countn=0;
 $('#gallery').on('click', '.gon', function() {
  // increment countn
 });
 $('.teaserbox').click(function() {
  // reset countn
 });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If `countn` is declared outside both the functions you should be able to do it. So something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var count = 0;

$('#gallery').on('click', '.gon', function() {   
countn = ($(this).data("click_count") || 0) + 1;
$(this).data("click_count", countn);
// set up for first move
if ( countn == 1 ) {
do something........
}

$('.teaserbox').click(function() {    
countn = 0; 
return false;       
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgio, but this doesn't work. Here is an example at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/actree/pNkMM/28/). After reset the alert will show "0". But after click the first div counter again, alert will show the total of all clicks on the first div. I want to start a new count from "0" after reset. Any hint?